# smarty variable in php

Tags: php, smarty

I have a problem. I have a variable of smarty which is assigned in a textbox like:

```
<input type="text" name="blogID" id="blogID" value="{$e.id}">
```

I want this text value in `{php}{/php}` and I want to select all data from a database table on this text box value. Here is an example:

```
{php}
$select = mysql_query("select * from tbl_blog where id = '".$_POST['blogID']."'");
{/php}
```

This is not working how can i solve it?

Comment: You should not use `mysql_query`, it is deprecated, and as you use it, it is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: input is spelled wrong, and is the form action taking you to the page that contains the query

Comment: Above all else, a call to `mysql_query()` _does not belong_ inside a Smarty template. That logic and its associated fetch loop should occur in the regular PHP code, with a call to `$smarty->assign(...)` to assign the query's resultant rowset into a variable for the Smarty template to use.

Comment: If you post the PHP code which creates the Smarty object and renders its template, we can help you get this logic into the right place.

Comment: so to whoever edited "inpyt" was that a typo on the askers side that could be causing part of ths issue

Comment: also I've never seen `{php}` before, is that a valid way of using the php tag. I was under the impression `<?php` and `?>` was the only way

Answer (score 0):

As others have said `mysql_query` is deprecated and PDO is good to protect from sql injection

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname = "database";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostname.";dbname=".$dbname."", $username, $password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_blog WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['blogID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$select = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on a lot of things-

1. What error are you getting, if any?
2. If you are including the `mysql_connect()` on the page somewhere?
3. Whether you're submitting the form as `post` on the same page?
4. You can also try encapsulating your php code in an `if()` block, like-

   ```
   {php}
   if (isset($_REQUEST['blogID'])) {

       $select = mysql_query("select * from tbl_blog where id = '".$_REQUEST['blogID']."'");
   }
   {/php}
   ```

Also I'd recommend having a separate document for php and using `$smarty->assign()` and not using the deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0):

{php} tags are deprecated from Smarty, and should not be used. Put your PHP logic in PHP scripts or plugin functions instead.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl